# Angularjs - grouping ng show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I group ng-shows without ruining the dom tree order?

Reason: I want to decrease the amount of watchers

For example I have these ng-shows:

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li ng-show="canEdit">C</li>
    <li ng-show="canEdit">D</li>
    <li ng-show="canEdit">E</li>
</ul>
```

Can I somehow do something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    {{ng-show-start(canEdit)}}
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
    {{ng-show-end(canEdit)}}
</ul>
```

Using an DOM element instead of ng-show-start&end can also be an solution, but it must be able to remove its element and show the contents on true.

Comment: Seems like the answer would depend on why you're grouping them. `<li ng-repeat="item in ['C', 'D', 'E']" ng-show="canEdit">{{item}}</li>`, for example.

Comment: The reason for grouping ng-shows is to minimize the $watchers, ng-repeat will return the same amount of watchers

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is three years old and probably irrelevant but there's the following solution in angular 1.2+

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li ng-show-start="canEdit">C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li ng-show-end="canEdit">E</li>
</ul>
```

The `-start` and `-end` postfixes can be used with `ng-show, ng-if, ng-switch, ng-repeat` and your own directives if `multiElement: true` is set.

Answer (score 0):

If `canEdit` is not going to change after the initial assignment then you can use a one time bind introduced in angular 1.3.  `ng-show="::canEdit"`. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

If you really want to group the `<li>` tags then you will need to wrap them in an html element and put the `ng-show` on it

I don't think you need to worry about too many watchers though.  I believe (though am not certain) that angular will only assign a single watcher to `canEdit` as it is a single variable that is being bound in multiple locations

Comment: Unfortunately angular will asign a watcher for each ng-show, and if canEdit was not going to change i would do this serverside.. not clientside. Thank you for your time